# Wrong expected value from cirq PauliString

Tags: cirq

I have to compute the exact expectation value from a state vector obtained after running a circuit. While I was running my code, I found different weird outcome so I decided to create few tests and I got the following results.

If I implement the Hamiltonian $H = \sigma_{0}^{z}+\sigma_{1}^{z}$:

```
import cirq

q0 = cirq.NamedQubit('q0')
q1 = cirq.NamedQubit('q1')

qc = cirq.Circuit()
qc.append(cirq.X(q0))
qc.append(cirq.X(q1))

hamiltonian = 0
hamiltonian += cirq.Z(q0)
hamiltonian += cirq.Z(q1)

num_var = { q0: 0, q1: 1 }
expectation_value = cirq.PauliString(hamiltonian).expectation_from_state_vector(qc.final_state_vector(), num_var).real
```

The outcome of `print(expectation_value)` is:

```
1.0
```

The correct result should be `-2.0` instead. I tried out different combinations and what I obtained is:

```
qc.append(cirq.I(q0))
qc.append(cirq.I(q1))

# here insert the hamiltonian computation

print(expectation_value) --> 1.0
```

Does somebody know what is going on? What is it wrong with my code? I am using `cirq 0.13.1` but I tested on`cirq 0.9.1` as well and it gave me the same results.

Thank you in advance! :)

I write down a more complex example with the Hamiltonian $H = \sigma_{0}^{z} + \sigma_{1}^{z} + \sigma_{0}^{z}\,\sigma_{1}^{z}$

import cirq

```
q0 = cirq.NamedQubit('q0')
q1 = cirq.NamedQubit('q1')

qc = cirq.Circuit()
qc.append(cirq.X(q0))
qc.append(cirq.I(q1))

hamiltonian = 0
hamiltonian += cirq.Z(q0)
hamiltonian += cirq.Z(q1)
hamiltonian += cirq.Z(q0)*cirq.Z(q1)


num_var = { q0: 0, q1: 1 }
expectation_value = cirq.PauliString(hamiltonian).expectation_from_state_vector(qc.final_state_vector(), num_var).real
```

The resulr of `print(expectation_value)` is `1.0` instead of `-1.0`.

Answer (score 4):

You want `cirq.PauliSum` instead of `cirq.PauliString`. Actually you had exactly that... but then asked for it to be converted to a `cirq.PauliString`.

It all got confusing because cirq.PauliString "helpfully" saw a class it didn't have an explicit conversion defined for, and tried a fallback strategy based on iterating that class looking for Pauli terms to multiply together. Which worked!... except it was iterating over terms that were supposed to be *added* together. Oops. So you get `I` because the sum `(Z0) + (Z1) + (Z1*Z0)` gets seen as the list `[Z0, Z1, Z1*Z0]` which is then interpreted in context as the product `(Z0) * (Z1) * (Z1*Z0)` which equals `I`. I [opened a cirq bug to raise an error instead when this occurs](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/issues/5009).